# how does sort method work when comparing many fields

Tags: javascript, sorting

I'm solving a programming problem.

and there is one thing I can't understand that is about sort.

first of all, show you the code.

```
var sumCount = { classic: 1450, pop: 3100 };
var songs = [
  { genre: 'classic', count: 500, index: 0 },
  { genre: 'pop', count: 600, index: 1 },
  { genre: 'classic', count: 150, index: 2 },
  { genre: 'classic', count: 800, index: 3 },
  { genre: 'pop', count: 2500, index: 4 }
]

var sortedSongs = songs.sort((a,b)=>{
               if(a.genre !== b.genre) {
                   return sumCount[b.genre] - sumCount[a.genre];
               }
               if(a.count !== b.count) {
                   return b.count - a.count;
               }
               return a.index - b.index;
           })
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

In this code, the function inside sort method is comparing genre, count, index. that is not only one like below code.
usually, I've used sort method like below code. the comparefunction is comparing about only array values.So the values will be changed from low to high step by step .

```
[1,3,4].sort((a,b) => a - b));
```

But I don't understand how songs'values are ordering with comparing about many fields. Could you guys give me some tip to wake up my brain so that I can understand it...

Thanks.

#### edit

here are steps that I logged before comparefunction return.

1. diff genre, swap: true, index:  1 0
2. diff genre, swap: false, index:  2 1
3. diff count, swap: false, index:  2 0
4. diff count, swap: true, index:  3 0
5. diff genre, swap: false, index:  3 1
6. diff genre, swap: true, index:  4 0
7. diff genre, swap: true, index:  4 3
8. diff count, swap: true, index:  4 1

And then I swapped the index following above steps,

```
1. swap index 1 with 0  
songs =[  
**{ genre: 'pop', count: 600, index: 1 },**  
**{ genre: 'classic', count: 500, index: 0 },**  
{ genre: 'classic', count: 150, index: 2 },  
{ genre: 'classic', count: 800, index: 3 },  
{ genre: 'pop', count: 2500, index: 4 }  
]  

2. no swap    
songs = [  
{ genre: 'pop', count: 600, index: 1 },  
{ genre: 'classic', count: 500, index: 0 },  
{ genre: 'classic', count: 150, index: 2 },  
{ genre: 'classic', count: 800, index: 3 }, 
{ genre: 'pop', count: 2500, index: 4 }  
]  

3. no swap  
songs = [  
{ genre: 'pop', count: 600, index: 1 },  
{ genre: 'classic', count: 500, index: 0 },  
{ genre: 'classic', count: 150, index: 2 },  
{ genre: 'classic', count: 800, index: 3 },  
{ genre: 'pop', count: 2500, index: 4 }  
]  
  
4. swap index 3 with 0    
songs = [  
{ genre: 'pop', count: 600, index: 1 },  
**{ genre: 'classic', count: 800, index: 3 },**  
{ genre: 'classic', count: 150, index: 2 },  
**{ genre: 'classic', count: 500, index: 0 },** 
{ genre: 'pop', count: 2500, index: 4 }  
]  

5.  no swap  
songs = [  
{ genre: 'pop', count: 600, index: 1 },  
{ genre: 'classic', count: 800, index: 3 },  
{ genre: 'classic', count: 150, index: 2 },  
{ genre: 'classic', count: 500, index: 0 }, 
{ genre: 'pop', count: 2500, index: 4 }  
]

6.  swap index 0 with 4 
songs = [  
{ genre: 'pop', count: 600, index: 1 }, 
{ genre: 'classic', count: 800, index: 3 },  
{ genre: 'classic', count: 150, index: 2 },  
**{ genre: 'pop', count: 2500, index: 4 },**  
**{ genre: 'classic', count: 500, index: 0 }**  
]  

7.  swap index 3 with 4  
songs = [  
{ genre: 'pop', count: 600, index: 1 },  
**{ genre: 'pop', count: 2500, index: 4 },**  
{ genre: 'classic', count: 150, index: 2 },  
**{ genre: 'classic', count: 800, index: 3 },**  
{ genre: 'classic', count: 500, index: 0 }  
]  

8. swap index 1 with 4  
songs = [  
**{ genre: 'pop', count: 2500, index: 4 },**  
**{ genre: 'pop', count: 600, index: 1 },**  
{ genre: 'classic', count: 150, index: 2 },  
{ genre: 'classic', count: 800, index: 3 },  
{ genre: 'classic', count: 500, index: 0 }  
]
```

I was able to get a different result than I expected...
It makes me confused... did I miss something?

Simply put, In this case, there is selection sort that is finding lowest number repeating all elements. And sort will sort all elements from lowest to highest. In the process, How is the genre sorted in the same time? Could you let me know it?  selection ,quick, whatever sort algorithm....
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BALcb.png

Comment: Just follow the code from top to bottom. The first `if` checks if the `genre` is different. If not we reach the second `if` and check if `count` is different. If not we then compare the `index`. So this first sorts the items by genre, then by count and then by index.

Comment: Your `sumCount` (genre-count) map can be determined via: `const sumCount = songs.reduce((acc, { genre, count }) => ({ ...acc, [genre] : (acc[genre] ?? 0) + count }), {});
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if we wanted to order the days in a work week?

```js
["Thursday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Friday", "Wednesday"].sort()
//=> ["Friday", "Monday", "Thursday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday"]
```

Obviously that doesn't work as we expected but JavaScript needs a little bit of help here:

```js
function Day(str, ord) {
  this.day = str;
  this.ord = ord;
}

Day.prototype.toString = function () { return this.day; };
Day.prototype.valueOf = function () { return this.ord; };

const days =
  [ new Day("Thursday", 4)
  , new Day("Monday", 1)
  , new Day("Tuesday", 2)
  , new Day("Friday", 5)
  , new Day("Wednesday", 3)
  ];

days.sort((a, b) => a < b ? -1 : 1);

days.map(d => String(d));
//=> ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"]
```

Here's another example: we want to display a list of cities sorted by country and name:

```js
const OrderCity = city => `${city.country}/${city.name}`; // sort of an "index"
const PrintCity = city => `${city.country}: ${city.name}`;

const cities =
  () =>
    [ {name: 'London', country: 'UK'}
    , {name: 'Manchester', country: 'UK'}
    , {name: 'Liverpool', country: 'UK'}
    , {name: 'Paris', country: 'France'}
    , {name: 'Marseille', country: 'France'}
    , {name: 'Lyon', country: 'France'}
    , {name: 'Brussels', country: 'Belgium'}
    , {name: 'Anvers', country: 'Belgium'}
    , {name: 'Liege', country: 'Belgium'}
    ];

cities()
  .sort((a, b) => OrderCity(a) < OrderCity(b) ? -1 : 1)
  .map(city => PrintCity(city))
  .join("\n");

//=> Belgium: Anvers
//=> Belgium: Brussels
//=> Belgium: Liege
//=> France: Lyon
//=> France: Marseille
//=> France: Paris
//=> UK: Liverpool
//=> UK: London
//=> UK: Manchester
```

Comment: And how does this answer OPs question: _"how songs'values are ordering with comparing about many fields."_ ?

Comment: @Andreas Thanks. Lexical sorting bites me every single time in JS! Fair enough I'll remove that section. As for this answer I believe it gives enough clues and information as to how OP would want to fix their particular issue while leaving it relatively open for others.

Answer (score 0):

Per documentation of [Array.prototype.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-us/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

> If compareFunction is supplied, all non-undefined array elements are sorted according to the return value of the compare function (all undefined elements are sorted to the end of the array, with no call to compareFunction). If a and b are two elements being compared, then:
>
> - If compareFunction(a, b) returns less than 0, sort a to an index lower than b (i.e. a comes first).
> - If compareFunction(a, b) returns 0, leave a and b unchanged with respect to each other, but sorted with respect to all different elements. Note: the ECMAScript standard only started guaranteeing this behavior in 2019, thus, older browsers may not respect this.
> - If compareFunction(a, b) returns greater than 0, sort b to an index lower than a (i.e. b comes first).
>   compareFunction(a, b) must always return the same value when given a specific pair of elements a and b as its two arguments.

So while you are used to seeing this:

```
function compareNumbers(a, b) {
  return a - b;
}
```

It is more generally represented as:

```
function compare(a, b) {
  if (a is less than b by some ordering criterion) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (a is greater than b by the ordering criterion) {
    return 1;
  }
  // a must be equal to b
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the example below, I have an array of sorters (with types string, function, and object):

```js
const sorters = [
  (a, b) => sumCount[b.genre] - sumCount[a.genre],
  'genre',
  { key: 'count', direction: 'desc' },
  'index'
];
```

I use these to sort the data top-down. I have utilized all three types of sorters within a loop. Each type of sorter evluates the two items within the current sort a bit differently.

**Note:** In your example, you use the difference in genre to determine if you compare the counts. You should instead compare the counts as one atomic comparison, followed by the genre name.

What you have:

```js
if (a.genre !== b.genre) {
   return sumCount[b.genre] - sumCount[a.genre];
}
```

Instead, do this:

```js
let diff;

diff  = sumCount[b.genre] - sumCount[a.genre]; // desc
if (diff !== 0) return diff;

diff = a.genre.localeCompare(b.genre); // asc
if (diff !== 0) return diff;

// ... continue to next field ...
```

---

### Full example

```js
const compareVals = (a, b) => {
  if (b == null) return -1;
  if (a == null) return 1;
  if (typeof a === 'string') return a.localeCompare(b);
  return a - b;
}

const compareWithSorter = (a, b, sorter) => {
  if (sorter == null) return 0;
  if (typeof sorter === 'function') return sorter(a, b);
  if (typeof sorter === 'string') return compareVals(a[sorter], b[sorter]);
  const dir = sorter.direction === 'desc' ? -1 : 1;
  return compareVals(a[sorter.key], b[sorter.key]) * dir;
};

const sortMulti = (arr, sorters) =>
  arr.sort((a, b) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < sorters.length; i++) {
      const res = compareWithSorter(a, b, sorters[i]);
      if (res !== 0) return res;
    }
    return 0;
  });

const songs = [
  { genre: 'classic' , count: 500  , index: 0 },
  { genre: 'pop'     , count: 600  , index: 1 },
  { genre: 'classic' , count: 150  , index: 2 },
  { genre: 'classic' , count: 800  , index: 3 },
  { genre: 'pop'     , count: 2500 , index: 4 }
];

const sumCount = songs.reduce((acc, { genre, count }) =>
  ({ ...acc, [genre] : (acc[genre] ?? 0) + count }), {});

const sorters = [
  (a, b) => sumCount[b.genre] - sumCount[a.genre],
  'genre',
  { key: 'count', direction: 'desc' },
  'index'
];

const sortedSongs = sortMulti(songs, sorters);

console.log(sortedSongs);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: Thanks man, I read your code carefully. But I am sorry I don't still understand a part of your code. CompareWithSorter return one result(0, -1 , 1) after calling one of functions depending on which sorter is got. And then sort method of arr finally return one of result (0, -1, 1). These results are decided by three standards(genre, count, index). I can guess sort method allow to use three standards. I mean the method is sorting genre( pop first, classic second ) as well as count ( from highest to lowest ).

Comment: How does it works?  Simply put, if There is selection sort that is finding lowest number  repeating all elements. And sort will sort all elements from lowest to highest. In the process, How is the genre sorted by same sort algorithm?  Could you let me know it. selection ,quick, whatever sort algorithm..

Answer (score 0):

Your code is essentially sort by `sumCount[song.genre]` in descending (`b - a`) order:

```
if(a.genre !== b.genre) {
  return sumCount[b.genre] - sumCount[a.genre];
}
```

If those are equal, sort by `song.count` in descending (`b - a`) order:

```
if(a.count !== b.count) {
  return b.count - a.count;
}
```

If those are equal, sort by `song.index` in ascending (`a - b`) order:

```
return a.index - b.index;
```

You could think of it as the following (SQL) pseudo-code:

```
ORDER BY sumCount[song.genre] DESC, song.count DESC, song.index ASC
```

Comment: If OP has problems to understand those `if()` blocks and the flow they create... Don't you think your "helper" functions might be a little bit too ambitious for OP?

Comment: @Andreas You might be right, I've replaced the snippet with some pseudo-code.